# UK young engineers' conference OR UK's young engineers conference

Tags: possessives

Which is more correct?

> UK young engineers' conference

or

> UK's young engineers conference

to denote a conference of young engineers in the UK and

a conference of young engineers of the UK and.

Also why?

Comment: As a title, it would be capitalized, UK Young Engineers Conference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your audience is  group of

> UK young engineers

and it is their conference

> UK Young Engineer's conference

You don't necessary need the possessive

> Since I'm one of the UK's young engineers,
>   I'll be going to the *UK Young Engineer* Conference in Brighton.

since it's a bundle of adjectives.